# Why is Sonarqube not analyzing .Net 4.5 c# code

Tags: c#, sonarqube

In my organization we have several projects. Some are in .Net 4.5 and other are been migrated to .Net Core.

All the projects go through a GOcd pipeline for delivery. This pipeline includes Sonarqube analysis.

The problem is that sonar is not analyzing the c# code of projects that are referencing .NET 4.5. The .Net Core projects are analysed as expected, but the 4.5 ones only get analyses on javascript, xml, css, etc... and not the actual c# code.

There are no errors/<s>warnings</s> being logged. Any ideas?

Details:
-Sonar 7.3
-Scanner 2.2
-MSBuild 14

Edit1:
Actually there are several warnings going on, so i created a empty project using the default asp.net mvc project for .net 4.5 and ran it through the pipeline... most of the warnings are

```
|15:02:31.034      2>CSC : warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer SonarAnalyzer.Rules.CSharp.SOMETHING cannot be created from C:\Users\TFS-SVC\AppData\Local\Temp\.sonarqube\.static\csharp_7.3.2.6129\SonarAnalyzer-7.3.2.6129.zip\SonarAnalyzer.CSharp.dll : 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.. [D:\Go\Agent\pipelines\Sonar_Teste_Build\POC.Net4.5andSonarQube\POC.Net4.5andSonarQube.csproj]`
```

Edit2:
I installed Microsoft.CodeAnalysis 1.3.1 and Microsoft.CodeAnalyses.CSharp 1.3.1 nuget packages but the warnings persist and only javascript and CSS gets analysed

Comment: Can you provide us with any log files or build logs? Primarily around the time when SonarQube detects the C# projects but doesn't scan.

Comment: Which version of MSBuild are you using? Referencing .NET 4.5 makes me think that you might be using unsupported version of MSBuild (and C# compiler). You need to use MSBuild 14 (VS 2015 Update 3) or MSBuild 15 (VS 2017). Posting the full logs in the SonarSource community thread you opened could help us find the problem much faster.

Comment: Ah, I see that you mentioned you are using Scanner 2.2 - you have to use SonarScanner for MSBuild if you want to analyze .NET projects.

Comment: ColinM and Valeri, i currently don't have access to the full logs, all I know is that the report doesnt mention any warnings/erros... i've solicited it and as soon as i get my hands on it ill post it...  I also updated the details with the MsBuild we're using (14)

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSource updated! pls check it out

Comment: @Leonardo, you need to either build with a version of Visual Studio 2015 (or Build Tools 2015) with Update 3, or you need to reference `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` nuget that is with version equal or greater to 1.3.2. In any case, if you are not already referencing `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`, I would strongly recommend updating the Visual Studio on your build machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m using VSTS pipeline and Sonar C# 7.15 but my C# code is not getting analyzed. I found that it requires MSBuild version 14+ but where do I specify in VSTS pipeline.